# How to extract specific data out of a complex sentence using regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to scrape data from complex sentence out of a log4net text file with a regular expression.

```
4012 09:47:03 INFO QueueController - method GetData(), Start = 15-3-2017 09:47:01, ElapsedSeconds = 1,9023, Task = 7514, Thread = 9
```

I need the following data:

```
Method = GetData()
Time = 09:47:03
Start = 15-3-2017 09:47:01
ElapsedSeconds = 1,9023
Task = 7514
Thread = 9
```

I searched the internet, but I cannot find how to do that in this more complex case. Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Comment: have you done a basic regex tutorial and tried yourself?

Comment: looks straightforward

Comment: @Jordy check answer below if this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
string text = "4012 09:47:03 INFO QueueController - method GetData(), Start = 15-3-2017 09:47:01, ElapsedSeconds = 1,9023, Task = 7514, Thread = 9";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(.*\s+)(?<Time>.*)(\s+INFO QueueController*)(.*method\s+)(?<Method>.*)(, Start\s+)(?<Start>.*)(, ElapsedSeconds =*)(.*\s+)(?<ElapsedSeconds>.*)(, Task =*)(.*\s+)(?<Task>.*)(, Thread =)(.*\s+)(?<Thread>.*)(.*)");
Match match = pattern.Match(text);

string method = match.Groups["Method"].Value;
string time = match.Groups["Time"].Value;
string start = match.Groups["Start"].Value.Replace("=","");
string elapsed = match.Groups["ElapsedSeconds"].Value;
string task = match.Groups["Task"].Value;
string thread = match.Groups["Thread"].Value;

Console.WriteLine("Method = " + method);
Console.WriteLine("Time = " + time);
Console.WriteLine("Start = " + start);
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed = " + elapsed);
Console.WriteLine("Task = " + task);
Console.WriteLine("Thread = " + thread);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This will give you output like this.

[image]